# Array to string conversion - upgrade to Laravel 5.5 in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, upgrade, middleware

I have upgraded from Laravel 5.4 to 5.5. It was working on Laravel 5.4

On logging in we pass validation it gives a E_NOTICE causing the app to fail.

```
 ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Array to string conversion
```

The errror references the following file on line 155

/shared/httpd/trushape-55/laravel-project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php

$response->headers->setCookie($this->duplicate(
$cookie, $this->encrypter->encrypt($prefix.$cookie->getValue(), static::serialized($cookie->getName()))
));

[CLick here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewt2V.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Follow this for reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#cookies

Comment: you have to return cookies like this : 
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('name-of-cookie', 'value-of-cookie'));

Comment: just make sure you have set correct cache configs. and valid php version. then use `php artisan optimize:clear` and try again.